# "dub: command not found" when docker-compose up

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

Basically, what I'm trying is to create a firstly an Ubuntu enviroment where execute a zookeeper and a kafka server.

Firstly, I created a dockerfile where I define the Ubuntu enviroment:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
RUN apt-get install -y dub
RUN apt-get install -y wget rsync

RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo

RUN wget https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/3.7.0/kafka_2.13-3.7.0.tgz
RUN tar -xvf kafka_2.13-3.7.0.tgz
RUN mkdir -p /home/servidor-kafka/kafka
RUN rsync -av --remove-source-files kafka_2.13-3.7.0/ /home/servidor-kafka/kafka/
RUN rm kafka_2.13-3.7.0.tgz

RUN wget https://downloads.apache.org/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.7.2/apache-zookeeper-3.7.2-bin.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf apache-zookeeper-3.7.2-bin.tar.gz
RUN mkdir -p /home/servidor-kafka/zookeeper
RUN rsync -av --remove-source-files apache-zookeeper-3.7.2-bin/ /home/servidor-kafka/zookeeper/
RUN rm apache-zookeeper-3.7.2-bin.tar.gz

WORKDIR /home/servidor-kafka/kafka

EXPOSE 9092 2181
USER docker

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Then I create my docker-compose.yml like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    user: "1000:1000"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 500
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    volumes:
      - /home/servidor-kafka/zookeeper

  kafka-broker-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka-broker-1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    user: "1000:1000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - /home/servidor-kafka/kafka
```

When I docker build it I get no problems but when I execute "docker-compose up" i get:

```
/etc/confluent/docker/configure: line 40: dub: command not found
```

Which is weird because I already `RUN apt-get install -y dub` in the dockerfile.

When running zookeeper and kafka.

Can I get some feedback? Thank you.

Comment: Please format your code _as code_. Right now I need to go in and delete all the backslashes you added; setting off the code blocks would have meant you wouldn't have needed to add them in the first place.

Comment: (also, it looks like the indentation in the YAML is broken; that's something you -- as the OP having the original file and knowing its correct indentation -- should [edit] and fix).

Comment: Anyhow -- what have you done by way of sanity-checking? If you get a shell in the container, does `dpkg -l dub` show you that the dub package is installed? Does `dpkg -L dub` show you the files _inside_ that package? If that set of files contains a `dub` executable, is it at a location in the PATH? Etc.

Comment: Nothing in your Compose file `build:` an image; you're using the prebuilt Kafka and ZooKeeper images, not your Dockerfile.  (If you're allowed to, using prebuilt images is often easier and more maintainable.)

Answer (score 0):

I've reduced the number of `RUN` statements in your `Dockerfile`. This should give you an image with fewer layers.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk dub wget rsync

RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo

RUN wget https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/3.7.0/kafka_2.13-3.7.0.tgz && \
    tar -xvf kafka_2.13-3.7.0.tgz && \
    mkdir -p /home/servidor-kafka/kafka && \
    rsync -av --remove-source-files kafka_2.13-3.7.0/ /home/servidor-kafka/kafka/ && \
    rm kafka_2.13-3.7.0.tgz

RUN wget https://downloads.apache.org/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.7.2/apache-zookeeper-3.7.2-bin.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf apache-zookeeper-3.7.2-bin.tar.gz && \
    mkdir -p /home/servidor-kafka/zookeeper && \
    rsync -av --remove-source-files apache-zookeeper-3.7.2-bin/ /home/servidor-kafka/zookeeper/ && \
    rm apache-zookeeper-3.7.2-bin.tar.gz

WORKDIR /home/servidor-kafka/kafka

EXPOSE 9092 2181
USER docker

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

But this will not address your problem. As pointed out by David Maze in the comments, your `docker-compose.yml` file is not referencing the `Dockerfile`, so with `docker-compose up` you are effectively just running the two prebuilt images mentioned there.

Are you planning on running another service using the `Dockerfile`? Or are you planning on using the `Dockerfile` to replace one or both of the services?

It's also not apparent where `dub` is being run. I built the image using the updated `Dockerfile` above and ran `dub` fine (it did complain about not finding a package manifest, but the actual `dub` command is found!).

You're going to need to provide more information so that we can replicate your problem.

[image]